# I am trying to install chef server 11.x on a RHEL6 ec2 instance and install knife using gem and getting error

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, chef-infra, knife

I am trying to install chef server 11.x on a RHEL6 ec2 instance on AWS and install knife using 
"gem install chef —no-ri —no-rdoc"
But I got following error. Please help me to resolve it.

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
..
.
ERROR:  Error installing chef:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
        /usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for ffi.h... no
checking for ffi.h in /usr/local/include,/usr/include/ffi... no
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no
checking for rb_thread_call_with_gvl()... no
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl()... no
checking for ffi_prep_cif_var()... no
creating extconf.h
creating Makefile

make
Configuring libffi
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ffi-1.9.3/ext/ffi_c/libffi/configure: line 550: 0: Bad file descriptor
make: *** ["/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ffi-1.9.3/ext/ffi_c/libffi-x86_64-linux"/.libs/libffi_convenience.a] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ffi-1.9.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ffi-1.9.3/ext/ffi_c/gem_make.out
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem '—no-ri' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: nori
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem '—no-rdoc' (>= 0) in any repository
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
yum install libffi-devel
```

that should fix it based on a quick google search

Answer (score 1):

Two issues:

1. You don't need to install chef-client to install chef-server, the two are independent.
2. The way to install chef-server is to go to http://www.getchef.com/chef/install/ and click on the Chef Server tab. Then select your OS and version and it will give you the link for the RPM.

You can find more detailed instructions for installing chef-server [in the documentation](http://docs.getchef.com/install_server.html).